# VSCode Python Extension "Downloading Microsoft Python Language Server" hangs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Starting yesterday, the Microsoft Python extension for VSCode hangs on downloading the Microsoft Python Language Server. I've seen posts on other forums about how to resolve this but so far none of the suggestions have worked in this case. Enabling Jedi instead of the Microsoft version doesn't work as Intellisense now seems to run off of the Microsoft version as well, and setting the HTTP SSL Proxy to not run hasn't solved it either.

Machine Information:
   *Linux 5.0.0-1032-azure #34-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

VSCode Information:
   *Version: 1.43.1*
   *OS: Darwin x64 19.3.0*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,works for me !

```
"python.jediEnabled": true,
"python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to Jedi via the settings:

```
"python.jediEnabled": true,
"python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

If that doesn't work then please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.